# How to link an archive without depending on an IDE?

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, winsock, command-prompt

I've been using a TCP sockets tutorial for C++, and came across the following line -

> Before we begin, you will need to include winsock.h and link libws2_32.a to your project in order to use the API that are necessary for TCP/IP. If this is not possible, use LoadLibrary() to load ws2_32.dll at runtime, or some similar method.

After some research, I found a source that claimed this could be done with the following two lines -

```
#include <winsock.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
```

However, one of the two seem to not be working (I assume that it would be the second line, as the first is fairly straightforward). Here is the code I am trying to run -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int main() {
    std::cout << gethostbyname("www.google.com") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code, which should be printing the IP address of Google, instead gives the following error -

> C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\ccOXoE0F.o:SC.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to 'gethosebyname@4'
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Some more googling revealed that the reason for this is an improper linking of the library. According to these sources, the only way to link this is through an IDE. I generally use Notepad++ along with the command prompt, and so I ask if it is possible to properly link this archive without using an IDE.

If it isn't possible, then it looks like I'll have to get back into using IDEs.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you are including winsock.h and trying to link with ws3_32.lib (which is Winsock 2). You should include winsock2.h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, IDEs have nothing to do with this, and your desire is correct and entirely understandable. Since you seem to be on Windows, I'm not sure what kind of command-line toolchain you are using, but if it's one of the GNU-compatible ones (GCC with MinGW, for example), then you can specify the `-lws2_32` linker flag to link against the library.

Comment: I'm currently using g++. Could you possibly elaborate what you mean? I'm a bit lost. How would I specify the linker flag to link against the library?

Comment: @Simon `g++ -o progname.exe progname.cpp -lws2_32`